# How to make program installed in /root available to user? bash PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, root

Sorry if this is trivial, I'm struggling to understand the PATH variable system.

I have `deno` (the js runtime) installed here `/root/.deno/bin/deno`

I have a user, let's say it's called `user0`. When I switch to that user with `su - user0`, how do I make `deno` available? Especially through a reboot.

––––––––

Edit: I got it working for `user0` by appending to the local `.bashrc` ie `~/.bashrc export PATH="/root/.deno/bin:$PATH"`

This works, but what is the best practice for installing executables that should be available to all users?

Comment: Only root should have permission to view contents of `/root`. Nobody else. Software available to all users (non-deb, non-snap, non-Flatpak, non-pip) should typically be located in `/usr/local/` Is there a reason you cannot use the typical location?

Comment: @user535733 No real reason. I'm using a remote server and just started installing what I thought I needed before creating other users. How do you suggest I remedy this? Uninstall from `/root/` and try again in `/user/local/`?

For context this was the install command I used for `deno`:

`curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh`

How do ensure that the binary is installed in `/user/local/`?